# How to define scopes in Access Token using AWSCognitoIdentityProvider ios SDK for Cognito

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito

I'm developing an ios swift app using `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider` ios SDK for cognito userpool. The backend implemented custom scopes which required the access token that I get from getSession() method contains all the scopes in order to call the API.

Currently, the scope that i get from `getSession()` is only

```
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
```

How can I get all the custom scopes to the access token?
Appreciate anyone who can help me.

Thank you